# NSSavepanel Fieldeditor

Tags: nssavepanel

I have some code to select the name, without extension, in an NSSavePanel, that I got off of the net a long time ago, and seemed to work fine at the time.  I just reused the code and it's now failing.  The error is that "[mySavePanel fieldEditor: NO forObject: nil]" is returning nil.  If I change "NO" to "YES", it returns a NSText item, but it's not the name editor in the NSSavePanel.

```
NSSavePanel *mySavePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
[mySavePanel setTitle: @"Restore File"];
[mySavePanel setMessage: @"Select a location and name to restore the file as:"];
[mySavePanel setNameFieldStringValue: currentRecord.originalName];

NSText *editor = [mySavePanel fieldEditor: NO forObject: nil];
if (editor)
{
    NSString *nameFieldString = [mySavePanel nameFieldStringValue];
    NSString *nameFieldExt = [nameFieldString pathExtension];
    if (nameFieldExt != nil)
    {
        NSInteger newLength = [nameFieldString length] - [nameFieldExt length] - 1;
        [editor setSelectedRange: NSMakeRange(0, newLength)];
    }
}
```

A bit stumped here, anyone have an idea why it would return nil?